# Are there any easy to use A/B Testing frameworks?

Tags: usability-testing, ab-testing

How to do A/B testing is a difficult problem. Are there any frameworks or tools out there that ease the pain?

Comment: Should by "any" rather than "and" in the title?

Comment: @ChrisF That's why I get for not proofreading.

Answer (score 4):

There is a google tool for web apps.

www.google.com/websiteoptimizer

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Django, there's Django-Lean ( http://bitbucket.org/akoha/django-lean/wiki/Home ).

There are also several webapps for building multiple landing pages and doing A/B testing on them:

- http://unbounce.com
- http://performable.com